# Shifting a function for convolution

Tags: convolution

We have $f(t)$, $h(t)$ and we want to compute the convolution of these two functions.

So we will have a dummy variable τ for the product: $f(\tau)h(t-\tau)$ as we know...

Why we are not permitted to consider this:

if: $h(t - \tau) = h(-\tau-(-t))$ is true

then $h(t - \tau)$ is constructed like this:

1. invert $h(\tau)$
2. shift $h(-\tau)$ on the **right** for a constant **(-t)**.
   **If t > 0** then the function will be shifted on the **left** by t.

Instead of the steps above we say:

a. $\phi(\tau) = h(-\tau)$

b. $\phi(\tau - t) = h[-(\tau-t)] = h(t-\tau)$

which means the opposite from steps 1-2:

first we invert $h(\tau)$ for having $h(-\tau)$ and then shift $h(-\tau)$ by $t$ having:
$h(t-\tau)$.

**In this case if t > 0 we obtain right shift instead of left shift from steps 1-2.**

It seems that the difference is among different constructive steps but which ones?

Thanks in advance.